# Where is PHP's gmtime()?

Tags: php

There are two standard C lib functions [gmtime() and localtime()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gmtime). They both return a struct like this (one in GMT, one in local TZ and daylight savings time):

```
struct tm {
    int tm_sec;         /* seconds */
    int tm_min;         /* minutes */
    int tm_hour;        /* hours */
    int tm_mday;        /* day of the month */
    int tm_mon;         /* month */
    int tm_year;        /* year */
    int tm_wday;        /* day of the week */
    int tm_yday;        /* day in the year */
    int tm_isdst;       /* daylight saving time */
};
```

PHP has a wrapper over [localtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.localtime.php), but to the best of my knowledge not gmtime(). What am I missing? Where PHP's gmtime() wrapper?

I did find one really old request for a PHP gmtime() - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=576&edit=1. But it's closed and dismissed as not needed. I don't agree.

I Don't *need* it. But conversion of a `struct tm` from local time to GMT is not trivial (AFAIK), so it would be nice to have. As nice as having localtime().

Comment: There is `gmdate` which creates a date/time from timestamp in GMT

Comment: @RamRaider yeah I know. Similar name but not the same:)

Comment: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/reentrancy.c#L105 and referenced https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/datetime.c#L54 - is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @MarkBaker https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/reentrancy.c#L105. Yeah that looks like it. gmtime_r() is the reentrant version. But what am looking at exactly?

Comment: [this implementation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.localtime.php#71632) looks like what you want

Comment: Oh cool. Should have read the comments. Haha. Looks like what I was half way through trying to write. Cheers. I'd take that as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In summary, @WouterHuysentruit pointed out that the absence of `gmtime()` is discussed in the comments on the PHP [localtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.localtime.php) documentation page. There's talk of it not being implemented on all systems properly or at all, which is surprising since its standard C89, and POSIX. In any case as Wouter pointed out there is also a PHP implementation of gmtime() in the comments which does the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

As the documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) states for the function time() :

“Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).”

So the gmtime is simply time().

Comment: No it isn't. `gmtime()` returns broken down time given a timestamp. `time()` returns the time as a timestamp.